# Export records from data extension automatically

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio

Need to export records from data extension automatically and send this exported file trough email. Is there any way to do this??

Thanks and Regards,
Usha Nagaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t attach it to an email, but you can use a [Data Extension Data Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_extension_extract.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) to place it in a file location. This can either be on MCs own FTP or on an external one.

Using FTP also doesn’t put you at risk of exceeding attachment file size limit imposed by inbox providers.

Comment: Hi Lukas 

Thanks for above update.

Regards,
Usha Nagaraj

Comment: You're welcome, @user80134 - remember to accept and upvote the answer if it has been helpful